# Applying Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the unit disk and satisfies Re$\,f(z)>0$ and $\,f(0)=c$. Show that
$$
\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\le \,f(z)|\le\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}.
$$

How do we prove this proof this? I know that we should define the function $F(z)=\dfrac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. First of all, in order for the inequality to hold, $|c|$ has to be equal to 1.

Set
$$
g(z)=\frac{f(z)-c}{f(z)+c}.
$$
Then $\,\mathrm{Re}\,f(z)>0$, implies that $|g(z)|<1$. Also, $g(0)=0$, and by virtue of Schwarz Lemma, $|g(z)|\le |z|$. Thus
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)-c}{f(z)+c}\right|\le |z|.
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{1-|f(z)|}{1+|f(z)|}\le |z|\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\le|f(z)|
$$
and
$$
\frac{|f(z)|-1}{|f(z)|+1}\le |z|\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}\ge|f(z)|.
$$

Comment: Seriously, I am confused with this solution. How $\left|\frac{f(z)-c}{f(z)+c}\right|\le |z|$   becomes $\frac{(1-|z|)}{(1+|z|)}≤|f(z)|≤\frac{(1+|z|)}{(1-|z|)}$

Comment: @dupsySee my edited answer.